# Improving performance in assigning values to a high dimensional numpy object

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Here is a subset of my code

```
def main():
   filename = "path/to/something" # sys.argv[1]
   B = list(SeqIO.parse(filename + ".fasta", "fasta"))
   A = np.array([parse_id(datum.id) for datum in B])
   maxit, maxpop, maxind, maxlocus = header_keys.max(axis=0) + 1
   maxsite = len(data[0].seq)
   x = np.full((maxit, maxpop, maxind, maxlocus, maxsite), 'a', dtype="S")
   for a, b in zip(A, B):
       x[tuple(a)] = b

main()
```

The process spends 95% of its time in this tiny for loop

```
for a, b in zip(A, B):
        x[tuple(a)] = b
```

How can I improve the speed of this code? Would cython be helpful here? Should I give up and code the whole thing in C?

---

Descriptions of the objects `A`, `B` and `x`

```
type(A) # `numpy.ndarray`
A.shape # (x, 4) --> x is a function of the parameters
A.ndim # 2
type(A[0][0]) # <type 'numpy.int64'>

type(B) # list
len(B) # x --> x is a function of the parameters
type(B[0]) # <class 'Bio.SeqRecord.SeqRecord'>

type(x) # <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
x.shape # (n, m, o, p, q) # depend on the parameters. The typical kind of values it would take would be (1, 20, 200, 10, 999999), that is a lot of sites and quite a bit of individuals.
```

Here is a minimalist example file and a piece of code that allows you to try out to improve this loop. (The file will likely be too short to detect any difference in performance. You might have to build a longer file by extrapolating the current file).

Example File

```
>it0pop0ind0locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop0ind1locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop0ind2locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop0ind3locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop0ind4locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop0ind5locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop0ind6locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop0ind7locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop1ind0locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop1ind1locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop1ind2locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop1ind3locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop1ind4locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop1ind5locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop1ind6locus0
ATGTTG
>it0pop1ind7locus0
ATGTTG
```

Comment: What are the typical dimensions of x (n, m, o, p, q)?

Comment: You may also benefit from extracting `seq` from each `SeqRecord` object prior to the zip.  Further, you could benefit from translating the nucleotides to a numeric format (`'A' 'C' 'G' 'T'` --> `0 1 2 3`) for storage in the array.

Comment: @wflynny Thanks for your comments. The dimensions of x I would be like to end up using are of the kind (10, 20, 400, 10, 999999) (I added this info to the post as well).

Comment: That is 800 trillion entries, meaning the array is 800TB.  Maybe you could describe what you're doing exactly as to avoid a possible [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Hum... well I intended to split the work into (1, 20, 400, 10, 999999) but this is still a lot of entries. I didn't realized that. I am simulating whole genomes. My model is coded in C and is quite efficient. My point is about how to From the file given in example (fasta format) I am willing to calculate the frequencies of each 4 possible nucleobasis (A, T, C, G) at each site (along the printed DNA sequence) at each locus (`locus`) in each subpopulation (`pop`) for each iteration (replicate simulation, `it`).

Answer (score 0):

From the way you described your problem in the comments, it looks like you want the single site frequency counts of each base at each site at each locus.  Just so we're clear, I understand frequency counts to be:

```
ACGTC
AGGTC
AGCTC   
ACCAC
TCGAG
```

yield something like:

```
pos 0: [('A', 4), ('C', 0), ('G', 0), ('T', 1)]
pos 1: [('A', 0), ('C', 3), ('G', 2), ('T', 0)]
pos 2: [('A', 0), ('C', 2), ('G', 3), ('T', 0)]
pos 3: [('A', 2), ('C', 0), ('G', 0), ('T', 3)]
pos 4: [('A', 0), ('C', 4), ('G', 1), ('T', 1)]
```

If that's the case, from the dimensions of `x`, it looks like the number of inds/loci/sites are relatively manageable (400, 10, 1000000).  If you can only parse the sequences from specific iterations/subpopulations/etc., I would personally do something like:

```
import numpy as np

# This takes a list of N sequences of length L and converts them to 
# a NxL array of integers so that computing frequencies is fast
def vectorize_seqs(seqs):
    trans_table = -np.ones(256, dtype='int')
    trans_table[np.frombuffer('ACGT', np.uint8)] = np.arange(4)
    return np.array([trans_table[np.frombuffer(seq, np.uint8)] for seq in seqs])

# Then compute the frequency counts
bins = np.arange(5, dtype=int)
vseqs = vectorize_seqs(seqs)
N, L = vseqs.shape
counts = np.array([np.histogram(vseqs[:,i], bins)[0] for i in range(L)])
freqs = counts / counts.sum(axis=1)[:,None]
# now you have either an array of Lx4 counts or Lx4 normalized frequencies
```

From here, you can store the Lx4 freqs/counts for each combination of iteration, subpopulation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't read it entirely yet but the number of sites is the last dimension of `x` which is very big. I will indeed have a lot of sites.

Comment: Yes, but (400, 10, 1e6) is manageable (1GB).  If you can separate your sequences out into chunks this size, calculate your frequency counts, then store those, it'll be the only way to sort through 800TB of nucleotides.